# RubyのcloneとdupとActiveRecordのcloneとdupは別物？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

### Rubyのcloneとdupの動き

#### クラス定義

```
class Hoge
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

#### clone

```
h = Hoge.new
hc = h.clone

h.name = 'name'
hc.name = 'clone'
h.name #=> 'name'
```

#### dup

```
h = Hoge.new
hd = h.dup

h.name = 'name'
hd.name = 'dup'
h.name #=> 'name'
```

### ActiveRecordのcloneとdupの動き

#### clone

```
p = Piyo.find(1)
p.name = 'name'
pc = p.clone
pc.name = 'clone'
p.name #=> 'clone'
```

#### dup

```
p = Piyo.find(1)
p.name = 'name'
pd = p.dup
pd.name = 'dup'
p.name #=> 'name'
```

### 挙動まとめ

Rubyのcloneとdupはどちらもオリジナルのアトリビュートを変更しない。
ActiveRecordのcloneはオリジナルのアトリビュートを変更する。
ActiveRecordのdupはオリジナルのアトリビュートを変更しない。

### 参考資料

- [ActiveRecord オブジェクトをコピーする – hello-world.jp.net](https://blog.hello-world.jp.net/ruby/809/)

> こちらの記事 を参考にさせていただきActiveRecord オブジェクトをコピーしようと思ったのですが、Rails3.1以降でdupとcloneの動作が逆になったようです。

RubyとARで違うような挙動な上に、途中で仕様が変わっているようで、混乱しています。私はRails4を想定しています。

* https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L356

> ```
> # :method: clone
> # Identical to Ruby's clone method.  This is a "shallow" copy.  Be warned that your attributes are not copied.
> # That means that modifying attributes of the clone will modify the original, since they will both point to the
> # same attributes hash. If you need a copy of your attributes hash, please use the #dup method.
> #
> #   user = User.first
> #   new_user = user.clone
> #   user.name               # => "Bob"
> #   new_user.name = "Joe"
> #   user.name               # => "Joe"
> #
> #   user.object_id == new_user.object_id            # => false
> #   user.name.object_id == new_user.name.object_id  # => true
> #
> #   user.name.object_id == user.dup.name.object_id  # => false
> ##
> # :method: dup
> # Duped objects have no id assigned and are treated as new records. Note
> # that this is a "shallow" copy as it copies the object's attributes
> # only, not its associations. The extent of a "deep" copy is application
> # specific and is therefore left to the application to implement according
> # to its need.
> # The dup method does not preserve the timestamps (created|updated)_(at|on).
> ```

RoRのソースを見てみましたが、ドキュメント（コメント）はあるようですが、`clone`と`dup`の実装は見当たりませんでした。

### 質問

- RubyのcloneとdupとActiveRecordのcloneとdupは別物なのでしょうか？
- 違うとした場合、具体的にどのように違うのでしょうか？
- `If you need a copy of your attributes hash, please use the #dup method.`と書いてあるのは`深いコピー`のことでしょうか？（Rubyのdupは浅いコピーなので別物になっている）

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> RubyのcloneとdupとActiveRecordのcloneとdupは別物なのでしょうか？

同じものです。`Method#owner` でメソッドが定義されたクラスが得られますが、下記のいずれも `true` になります。

```
Piyo.new.method(:clone).owner == Object.method(:clone).owner`
Piyo.new.method(:dup).owner == Object.method(:dup).owner`
```

ただし、`clone` の場合は `initialize_clone`、`dup` の場合は `initialize_dup` メソッドが呼ばれます (参考: [initialize_clone, initialize_dup and initialize_copy in Ruby: Jon Leighton](http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2011/initialize_clone-initialize_dup-and-initialize_copy-in-ruby/))。

ActiveRecord の場合、`ActiveRecord::Core#initialize_dup` が定義されていますので、`dup` の挙動はここで変化しています。

> 違うとした場合、具体的にどのように違うのでしょうか？

### Object#dup, clone

Object の dup, clone はインスタンス変数をコピーしますが、これは浅いコピーであり、同じオブジェクトを参照します。

例では `h.name = "name"` とした時点で、`@name` が異なるオブジェクトを参照するので、`hc` に変更を加えても、影響がありません。

しかし、浅いコピーなので、同じオブジェクトを参照している状態で、そのオブジェクトに変更を加えると、両者に変更が及びます。

```
h = Hoge.new
h.name = "name"
hc = h.clone
hc.name.upcase!
h.name #=> "NAME"
```

### ActiveRecord::Base#clone

ActiveRecord::Base の clone は Object の clone と同じです。

ただし、ActiveRecord::Base では属性を 1 つの Hash に入れて、インスタンス変数に保持しています。

clone した場合は、同じ Hash を参照することになるので、属性の変更が clone 元にも及びます。上記の **同じオブジェクトを参照している状態で、そのオブジェクトに変更を加える** ケースに該当します。

### ActiveRecord::Base#dup

ActiveRecord の dup は initialize_dup が定義されているので、そこに違いが現れます。

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L382 を見ると、`@attributes.deep_dup` で属性の深いコピーを作成したり、主キーを nil にする処理が含まれています。

これにより、dup 元・dup 先は異なる Hash を参照することになるので、片方の変更がもう一方に影響しなくなります。

> If you need a copy of your attributes hash, please use the #dup method.と書いてあるのは深いコピーのことでしょうか？（Rubyのdupは浅いコピーなので別物になっている）

上記のように `dup` は `deep_dup` メソッドにより、属性の深いコピーが作成されます。
`deep_dup` の実装は https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/efff6c1fd4b9e2e4c9f705a45879373cb34a5b0e/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/deep_dup.rb です。